# How to sort elements in an ArrayList of Strings?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

```
 PhoneBookCollection phoneBook = new PhoneBookCollection();
```

I have an `ArrayList` of `PhoneBook` objects. (The getCollection method returns the list)

```
ArrayList<PhoneBook> list = phoneBook.getCollection();
```

I then iterate through my ArrayList and get the `PhoneBook` at the i'th index and get its corresponding `Telephone`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ ){

String phone = phoneBook.getPhoneBook(i).getTelephone();

}
```

What I want to be able to do now is sort the `getTelephone` objects in ascending order.
I know that ArrayLists don't have a sort method so i'm having a bit of trouble doing this.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: Assuming your PhoneBooks aren't comparing by Telephone Number, you could write a `PhoneBookComparator` and use `Collections.sort()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class that implements `Comparator`:

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<PhoneBook> { // Replace PhoneBook with the appropriate
    @Override
    public int compare(PhoneBook t1, PhoneBook t2) {
        return t1.getNumber().compareTo(t2.getNumber()); // Here compare the telephone numbers
    }
}
```

Then do this:

```
Collections.sort(list, new CustomComparator());
```

Comment: I understand the part where you are comparing the 2 Telephone numbers but where would I do do `Collections.sort(list, new CustomComparator());`?

Comment: It depends in **when** and **where** you want to sort your `ArrayList`.

Comment: I only want to sort the Phone Numbers not the whole `ArrayList` as a `PhoneBook` object stores other attributes such as name, address etc...

Comment: So you want another ArrayList with just the telephones sorted?

Comment: Looks like another collection is the only way to sort the telephones only... but I'm going to have to loop again and that increases time complexity

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java.util.Collections class to sort the lists. Use Collections.sort().

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [java.util.Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

The best will be use standart way with `java.util.Collections`

String class has method `compareTo()` and will be sorted automtically:

> Collections.sort(nameOfList)